Do DOM events create new functions in memory or just store a reference to an event
These buttons have the same event, do 2 of these functions get created separately in memory or event just points to a static function
I am not sure how to tell if the functions that get attached are the same objects or not.
<div style="padding: 5px">
   <button id="playerOne" onclick="onClick(event)"> One </button>
   <button id="playerTwo" onclick="onClick(event)"> Two </button>
</div>


There is just one onClick() function. A function call does not create a new function, to put it another way.

@Pointy I don't think the question is about the onClick() function, it's about the event listener function that's synthesized to call it, i.e. function(event) { onClick(event); }.

The simple answer is that this is implementation-dependent. The DOM parser could detect equivalent onevent attributes and merge them, but I don't think there's any requirement to do so.

@Barmar oh I see what you mean. Well wouldn't checking the resulting value of the "onclick" properties of the DOM nodes provide a clear answer? (Well "clear" for the browser involved.)

But in any case you shouldn't worry about that and just run away from event handler content attributes because "these are bad" (source: trust me)

‘These buttons have the same event’ - no they don’t. They happen to call the same function when a click event occurs on that element. The events are distinct. The function is the same.

Both onClick attributes point to the same function in memory, even though each button has its own onClick handler.
You can verify it by comparing both the event handlers -
if(document.getElementById('playerOne').onClick === document.getElementById('playerTwo))

If this returns true it means both are pointing to the same reference.

Well sure, but document.getElementById('playerOne').onClick is undefined.

it would return false

Take care with upper and lowercase. Also it’s usually a good idea to check your code. With the correct case characters the test will return false.
